# Why is Play application not able to resolve dependencies from inside docker container?

Tags: sbt, docker, playframework-2.2

I am trying to get a Play Framework application running inside a docker container on an Ubuntu Server 14.04 machine.

```
$ docker pull mzkrelx/playframework2-dev:2.2.3
$ docker run -i -t -v /path/to/play/app:/opt/workspace -p 9000:9000 mzkrelx/playframework2-dev:2.2.3

  bash-4.1# play
  [play-application] $ run
```

The last command results in attempts to resolving dependencies but only puts out errors, warnings and infos such as `You probably access the destination server through a proxy server that is not well configured.`

What do I do wrong?

Comment: If this is for production, rather than using `play run`, use `play dist` and package up a binary distributable, then put *that* in the docker container.  You can also use the `sbt-docker` plugin which will build and push your container for you with the distributable.

Comment: Thank you for these approaches! Following the usage proposition for this container image, it should also work the way I described above.

Comment: If you start a container with bash and run the command by hand from inside, does it work?

Comment: I don't have the Play Framework available in a simple bash container. Or do I misunderstand you?

Comment: At first start play tries to resolve some sbt dependencies by accessing the typesafe repositories. I guess you run this from inside a corporate environment where you have to use a http proxy to access the web. So you have to configure this http proxy by passing the usual 'http.proxyHost' and 'http.proxyPort' properties to the java (play) process.

Comment: @MarcusLinke On the same machine, in the same environment, but outside the docker container, dependencies resolve without specifying any proxy port or host.

Comment: @Steven Just read you fixed your problem already, but anyhow if there is a proxy between the docker host and the web you have to configure it for the container/application via environment variables/jvm properties explicitly regardless whether it is configured well at the docker host level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems as if my problems were network-related and subject to caching behaviour. The same setup now works perfectly. After a shutdown of the machine and a `play clean`.
Thanks for your help nevertheless!